# Properties of Sinkhorn distance

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, distance, wasserstein

I am reading the paper by Cuturi http://www.marcocuturi.net/Papers/cuturi13sinkhorn.pdf and I am curious about the properties of Sinkhorn distance and wondering what properties of the Sinkhorn distances carry over for the Wasserstein distances ($W_1$ and $W_2$).

More specifically, in section 4.4.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05500.pdf, they show $W_2$ has non negative sectional curvature and $W_1$ is flat. Let us assume for simplicity, we are concerned with probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My questions are:

1. Is it still true that the same properties hold if the metric is now replaced by Sinkhorn distance?
2. If $S_{\lambda}$ is the distance, is the following true: $S_{\lambda}(aX,aY) = |a|S_{\lambda}(X,Y)$? where $X \sim \mu, Y \sim \nu$.

I tried proving the 2nd result and now I am not even sure if it is true.

Comment: Did Cuturi himself create the Sinkhorn distance, rather than Sinkhorn, and is the Sinkhorn distance merely just the Kotorovich OT formulation but with entropic regularization added in?

Comment: I believe Cuturi defines the distance and he uses the Sinkhorn algorithm to solve the problem. And yes Sinkhorn distance is basically OT with an entropic regularizer added in.

Comment: do you know a source that derives the first derivative of the Sinkhorn distance? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867675/first-derivative-of-the-entropy-regularized-wasserstein-distance